# Creating a button that requires input from functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, return

I have a custom HTML section built into a Weebly website and a database that the JavaScript code is searching and plotting various data from. I have managed to set up the function to grab the data and plot it and call a function to create the download. The HTML then attempts to create a button to call the function. The part I have not been able to achieve is getting the variables from the JavaScript function to the HTML button. When the page renders, it downloads the file (due to the JavaScript calling the function). When the button is pressed nothing happens and the console logs an error (because the parameters were not passed from the function.

Ultimately the question is: is there a way to either a) create a button within the JavaScript function b) globally save the variables and create buttons in the HTML portion. I have posted the general code below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have edited the code to show the entire code, and also attempted to implement Camilos idea of using the event listener and createElement functions.

```
<head>
<title>Chart Experimentation</title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.16.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
// Sets up the canvas' for plots later on
<div class="chart-container">
<canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
<canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
// configures the tables that are going to be read through aws (you can 
ignore this)
AWS.config.update({
region: "My Region",
accessKeyId: "Key",
secretAccessKey: "Secret Key"  
});
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var table;
var tableName = "SkrootSensorTables";
function func1(sensorID, date, chartID) {
    var params = {
        TableName : tableName,
        KeyConditionExpression: "SensorID = :sid and #tim = :dat",
        ExpressionAttributeNames:{
            "#tim": "Timestamp"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":sid" : sensorID,
            ":dat" : date
        }
    };

    docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
        } else {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
            console.log(data);        
            chart(data, chartID);
        }
    });
}
// This is an intermediate step, you can ignore this
function chart(data, chartID) {
    table = data;
    try {
        tableName = table["Items"][0]["TableName"];
        sensorID = table["Items"][0]["SensorID"];
        queryAndChartData(tableName, sensorID, chartID);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Finally')
        throw "Exit Error";
    }
}
// This is an intermediate step in finding the data that will be charted (you 
can ignore this)
function queryAndChartData(tableName, sensorID, chartID) {
    console.log(tableName, sensorID, chartID);

    var params = {
        TableName : tableName
    };
    // This reads the data and finds the values that will be plotted
    docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

        // refine the data to chart it
        times = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data["Items"].length; i++) {
            var t = data["Items"][i]["Timestamp"];
            times.push(t);
            console.log(t);
            }

            readings = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data["Items"].length; i++) {
                var r = data["Items"][i]["Reading"];
                readings.push(r);
                console.log(r);
            }
            var ctx1 = document.getElementById(chartID).getContext('2d');
            var myChar1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: times,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Sensor ID: " + sensorID,
                        data: readings,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 200, 255, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 200, 255, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                }
            });
            // This is where I am trying to implement Camilos response
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.addEventListener('click', function auxfunc() {
                download_csv(times, readings);
            });
        }
    });
}
    function download_csv(time,readings) {
    var csv = 'Time,Reading\n';
    var data = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < readings.length; i++){
    data.push([time[i], readings[i]])
    console.log(datas)
    }
    data.forEach(function(row) {
        csv += row.join(',');
        csv += "\n";
    });

    console.log(csv);
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'SensorData.csv';
    hiddenElement.click();
}

// Creates plots for each day of the month (I realize there are better ways to record time)
// a) Ideally creates a download button below each plot (I haven't been able to figure this out)
var j = 1
for (var i = 6012020; i <= 6302020; i += 10000) {
    var Time = i
    var ChartName = "myChart" + j
    try {
        func1("33B178", Time, ChartName);
    setTimeout(() => {j++}, 2000);
    console.log(j)
    }
    catch(err) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
    }
}
</script>
// b) Ideally this would be able to receive the ouput of the function to use as imputs for the 
// download_csv function (it would also require a loop to create it for each plot.)
// <button onclick="download_csv()">Download CSV</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in order to add a button for each plot, you can use the [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method to create a new button inside your javascript code. It would look something like this:

```
const button = document.createElement('button');
```

And then you can specify which function it will call when clicked by using the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method. It would look something like this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', download_csv);
```

And finally you would have to run it inside a loop so that multiple buttons are created, and make sure to insert them after their respective charts. I'm not familiar with weebly so I'm not sure how it creates the charts, but you can add the buttons after the charts by getting the chart node using something like [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) if the charts an id for each, and then using [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to insert it. If you add the full html code to your question I might be able to give something more specific

So after you do that you should have a button after each graph, but when you click on any of the it doesn't pass the time and readings parameters. To do this, you have two options, you can use the [bind](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to create a new function with the parameter already specified like this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', download_csv.bind(this, times, readings));
```

Don't worry too much about the `this` parameter.

Or you could instead pass a function that calls the `download_csv` function with the required params, like this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function auxFunc() {
    download_csv(times, readings);
});
```

Once you add that they should be able to download the csv.

From looking at your code I assume you'd want to put all the code that I've explained inside the `func1` function (If you put it inside func1 then there would be no need for you to create the buttons in a loop since the `func1` function is already being called inside a loop). If you don't want it to download the csv as soon as you open the page, remove the `download_csv(times, readings);` line at the end of `func1`

## Edit 1

From what I can see, buttons aren't showing because you haven't inserted them into the DOM tree. If I understand your code correctly, and you want to insert the button after each canvas, then you'd have to do something like this:

```
const chartElement = document.getElementById(chartID);
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function auxfunc() {
    download_csv(times, readings);
});
chartElement.parentNode.insertBefore(button, chartElement.nextSibling);
```

This way the button will be inserted right after the canvas.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I want, thanks for  the quick response! I went ahead and attempted to make the edits you have suggested, but the button does not currently appear. I have posted the full code for you to look over, thanks in advance!

Comment: @CameronGreenwalt checkout my edit, basically you have to insert the button into the DOM tree

Comment: Yes this does exactly what I want now! The button appears just below the plot and creates a download button for each one, thank you so much, this would have taken me forever to figure out!